# Ошибка генерации во вложенном цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Точнее, не ошибка, а недостаток знаний о работе этих циклов. Имеется код:

```
from tkinter   import *
from random    import *

class GameWindow(Frame):

   def __init__(self, parent):
      Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.map = [[0]*256]*256
      self.parent = parent
      self.initUI()

   def initUI(self):
      self.parent.title("Game")
      self.parent.title("Game")     
      self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

      self.canvas = Canvas(self)
      self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

   def genMapCell(self):
      variant = paretovariate(10)
      return '#%06X' % int(round(variant-int(variant),6) * 1000000)

   def genMap(self):
      for x in range(255):
         for y in range(255):
            self.map[x][y] = self.genMapCell()

   def drawMap(self):
      for x in range(255):
         for y in range(255):
            self.canvas.create_line(x, y, x+1, y, fill=self.map[x][y])

def main():
   root = Tk()
   app = GameWindow(root)
   app.genMap()
   app.drawMap()
   root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Функция **genMap** должна заполнять массив рандомными значениями (за генерацию конкретного значения отвечает функция **genMapCell**). Ну, она и заполняет, только по строкам, в результате чего отрисовка даёт вот такой результат:

[image: ошибочная генерация]

Однако, если вставить строку **self.map[x][y] = self.genMapCell()** в такой же вложенный массив в функции отрисовки **drawMap**, то выходит что надо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я, если честно, уже как-то сталкивался с такой ошибкой, и мне удалось её решить. А сейчас додуматься не могу... В чём может быть причина такой "построчной вариативности"? Или как это называется...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта строчка

```
self.map = [[0]*256]*256
```

делает 256 ссылок на один список. Изменение элемента в одном списке меняет этот же элемент во всех 255 остальных.

Сделайте например так:

```
a = [[0]*256]*256
self.map = [x[:] for x in a]
```

Или так:

```
self.map = [[0]*256 for _ in range(256)]
```

Comment: Кст, если в `for` значение не планируете использовать замените его `_`: `[[0]*256 for _ in range(256)]`